# How to groupby and count since the first non nan value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df`:

```
         CODE    TMAX
0        000130  NaN
1        000130  NaN
2        000130  32.0
3        000130  32.2
4        000130  NaN
5        158328  NaN
6        158328  8.8
7        158328  NaN
8        158328  NaN
9        158328  9.2
...      ...     ...
```

I want to count the number of non nan values and the number of nan values in the 'TMAX' column. But i want to count since the first non NaN value and by code.

Expected result in code 000130: 2 non nan values and 1 NaN values.

Expected result in code 158328: 2 non nan values and 2 NaN values.

Same with the other codes...

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need `CODE`s too add [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) and count values by [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
m = df.TMAX.notna()
s = m[m.groupby(df['CODE']).cummax()]
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['CODE'], s).rename(columns={True:'non NaNs',False:'NaNs'})
print (df1)
TMAX    NaNs  non NaNs
CODE                  
130        1         2
158328     2         2
```

If need explicitely filter also column `CODE` by `mask`:

```
m = df.TMAX.notna()
mask = m.groupby(df['CODE']).cummax()
df1 = pd.crosstab(df.loc[mask, 'CODE'], m[mask]).rename(columns={True:'non NaNs',False:'NaNs'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `first_valid_index` to find the first non-NaN index and filter. Then use `isna` to create a boolean mask and count the values.

```
def countNaN(s):
    return (
        s.loc[s.first_valid_index():]
        .isna()
        .value_counts()
        .rename({True: 'NaN', False: 'notNaN'})
    )

df.groupby('CODE').apply(countNaN)
```

Output

```
CODE
000130  notNaN    2
        NaN       1
158328  notNaN    2
        NaN       2
```

Comment: Yes. It might be slower due to apply @jezrael